# Is there a way to store the response of set-backend-service base-url in a variable and modify the response to form our own JSON output?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy, apim

I am trying to execute azure table storage through APIM inbound policy. I am sending request through set-backend-service base-url. But I am not able to access the response from the backend URL and modify it according to the requirement.

I am using the below Script to get the response and I am trying to form my own JSON structure.
But apart from xml-to-json I am not able to do anything.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none">
        <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
        <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
    </cache-lookup>
    <set-variable name="SASToken" value="@("sas key")" />
    <set-variable name="TableStorageURL" value="@{string sastoken = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("SASToken");return String.Format("https://storagedev.table.core.windows.net/data()?{0}", sastoken);}" />
    <set-backend-service base-url="@($"{context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("TableStorageURL")}")" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <xml-to-json kind="direct" apply="always" consider-accept-header="false" />
    <cache-store duration="1000" cache-response="true" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`set-body` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-body-policy) in the `outbound` scope to fetch the response from your backend and change as per your needs.

You could even skip the `xml-to-json` policy.

Also, consider using liquid templates which further simply how you transform your response.